# How can I demo a website at localhost:3000 but make the address bar show http://mysite.com?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, url, browser, localhost

I'm going to be demoing a website I've developed. I want to run it locally but make it look like it's running on production.

This means I'll be interacting with the local web server on my computer at http://localhost:3000. Is there a convenient way I can actually make the browser's address bar look like http://www.mysite.com/ instead of showing localhost though?

Comment: Have you tried editing your /etc/hosts (*nix) or hosts.txt (win)? That'd be the easiest way to do it.

Answer (score 2):

Add a `hosts` entry mapping `mysite.com` to `127.0.0.1`. (and remember to remove it later)

There's not much you can do about the port, although you could host the whole thing in an `<iframe>` running on port 80.
Or you could just change the port of the demo, which shouldn't be too hard to do.

Answer (score 1):

Not unless you can run the server on `localhost:80`.  If you run on port 3000, the best you can do is to make your local machine think www.mysite.com is 127.0.0.1 by adding:

```
127.0.0.1     www.mysite.com
```

to your hosts file (/etc/hosts or C:\Windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts).  If you're happy with http://www.mysite.com:3000/, you can leave the server on port 3000.